# Which library should I use for client-server osgi

Tags: java, scala, osgi

I am considering using osgi in a typical java-swing client-server application.

I would like to break the server code into osgi services and then mark some of them as 'remotely exported' and then have a bundle which makes these services avaliable to the client. The client would also use osgi and include a bundle which connects to the server and makes the exported services available as local services.

We currently use some rmi-like code which just exposes a single interface over a socket.

I have looked into.

- [r-osgi](http://r-osgi.sourceforge.net/) last release Jan 2009, got a null pointer exception when I tried it, doesn't automatically register services locally
- [cfx](http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi.html) appears to be soap/rest only. and we have large payloads
- [ecf](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/) Not much documentation when using outside eclipse. Not sure what to download or how to get started

Other points to note:
 - We need it to use ssl and also apply some authentication on connecting
 - It needs to reconnect if the server gets restarted
 - The code is actually scala

I could just add to our existing rmi-like code but I'd rather use an existing library

Thanks for any advice or experiences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [OSGi 4.2 specification](http://www.osgi.org/Download/File?url=/download/r4v42/r4.cmpn.pdf), there exist Remote Services Specification (chapter 13).

By now, only 3 frameworks implements this specification: ECF, Apache CFX and Paremus.

I am using ECF because is the most mature open-source implementation right now. BTW, ECF includes R-Osgi as an available transport mechanism (R-OSGi is not OSGi 4.2 compliant as standalone) and other discovery and distribution mechanisms (Zookeper, REST...). There is a good integrators guide [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EIG%3aIntegrators_Guide).

OSGi guru Neil Bartlett also recommended me (via twitter ;) the [Paremus](http://www.paremus.com/) implementation. He said that is the most complete and functional one, but it cost money. Maybe you should take a look.